# Ignore changes and upload specific version with AnkhSVN and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I use Visual studio 2010 and AnkhSVN 2.3.10838 for Subversioning, I add some files and modify some others but now I think I made a mistake and need to ignore all my changes and get back to some specific version, I try **Revert**, **Update to specific version**, **switch solution**, but all of them keep my changes and update other files or add two files for each version, Is there any way to ignore (Delete All maybe)  my changes and back to specific version?

Answer (score 1):

Revert will cause the state of the file to go back to the last committed state.

For "Update to specific version" you need to select the type from the type drop down menu. For example revision will let you go back to a committed version of your choice.

From what I understand switch solution allows you to change the URL of your repository, so for example you could work on a branch rather than trunk, so is probably not what you want.

Try using update to specific version with revision as the type.

You could also use View History on a file, View Project History on a project or View Solution History on a solution, which will then show you all the relevant revisions and then right click on the revision you want to revert to see the revert options.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to browse by using the repo explorer, and check what revision you need to revert to.

Then when you do : revert to specific version, in the dropdownlist, select : specific version, and select the correct revision. 
That should roll you back to the correct version.